# bash-command to invert white-list of file paths to generate black-list

Tags: bash, path

I want to convert a white-list of file paths into a  black-list (minimum length) of file paths for a given directory.

I have a list of directories, that I want to keep  with all subfolders and files in it.

I want to invert this information is the sense of getting:  the minimum number of "delete directory with subfolders" commands so that the result is keeping the folders of the whitelist including subfolders and files.  (Just to explain. I do not want to delete anything. )

**Example:** 
data structure:

```
/A1/
        A2/
        B2/
                A3
                B3
        C2/
/B1/
        A2/
                A3
        B2
/C1/
        A2
        B2
/D1
```

whitelist.txt

```
/A1/B2  # also keep subdirs!
/C1/B2
```

wanted blacklist.txt

```
/A1/A2
/A1/C2
/B1      # no subdirs in whitelist -> no individual items here!
/C1/A2  
/D1
```

**I want to generate  blacklist.txt**

Is there a simple way to do it with **bash commands**?
Otherwise I would like to try it with python.

Comment: If i understand the question correctly you can just use `find` with the `prune` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bash script version

```
whitelist=( "./A1/B2" "./C1/B2" )

function run_path {
    local cpath cdir wdir allb bdirs
    cpath=${1:-.}
    cpath=${cpath%/}

    for wdir in "${whitelist[@]}"; do
        if [[ $wdir = $cpath ]]; then
            # break the recursive call
            # exit_status <>0 => false
            return 1
        fi
    done

    allb=1
    bdirs=()
    for cdir in "$cpath"/*/; do
        if [[ -d $cdir ]]; then
            # exit_status <>0 => false : found whitelist item
            if ! run_path "$cdir"; then
                allb=0
            else
                bdirs+=("$cdir")
            fi
        fi
    done

    if [[ $allb = 0 ]]; then
        for cdir in "${bdirs[@]}"; do
            echo "$cdir"
        done
        return 1
    fi

}

run_path "${cur_path}"
```

Comment: Absolutely great. Thank you very much for your work and for your time!